# user tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In oracle, user tables is a collection of tables created and contain user information. The code to describe tables owned by the user is

```
select *
from user_tables;
```

How to do it in MYSQL workbench?

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Comment: thanks! that really help

Answer (score 0):

Check out the tables in the `information_schema` database. The tables in that database contain a wealth of meta information about the databases in your MySQL instance.